# Bootstrap Validator Language - How can I control the language of error message using?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am following the example to create the form validation function
http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-usage

But I found that I am not able to change the language of error message language, I wanna set the error message in different language in my website. How can it be?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Did you receive any errors?

Answer (score 4):

Documentation reads:

> Error messages for individual form fields can alternatively be specified through the use of data attributes. You can specify an error message for each type of validator on a field, i.e. data-match-error="" or use data-error="" for a blanket error message to show for any errors on that field.

So if you want to have e.g. an alternative minlength error message, add

```
data-minlength-error="Your individual error message in a different language."
```

to the input field.

Comment: yeah, i knew about it. I just wonder if the language of error message can be set, is it auto-detect the language from user browser?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the default error message depends on the browser locale (google for `HTML5 form validation language`).

You have to set an individual error message like @Steve suggested to not depend on the brwoser language.